# What does nmbd stand for?

Tags: netbios

What does daemon "nmbd" stand for?
I want to know where come from the abbreviation to help remember the daemon name.

I assumed *N*et*B*IOS *d*aemon. But what stand for remaining "m"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The initials of nmbd stand for NetBIOS Message Block Daemon. The nmbd server daemon understands and replies to NetBIOS name service requests such as those produced by SMB/CIFS in Windows-based systems.

The smbd server daemon provides file sharing and printing services to Windows clients. The initials of smbd stand for Server Message Block Daemon.

The nmbd and smbd daemons are controlled by the smb (Server Message Block) service.

<sup>**Source:** [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Samba Daemons and Related Services](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-samba-daemons.html)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

nmbd stands for NetBIOS name server daemon

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Well, that's how nmbd(8) calls it.